# Permutation of combinations with a certain property

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, permutation-cycles

Let $1 \le k \le n$ be integers and let $S_k$ be the set of all $k$-size subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. I am interested in conditions on $n$ and $k$, such that there exists a permutation $\pi$ of $S_k$ such that the consecutive sets of $S_k$ according to $\pi$ have at least $1$ element in common (including the last and the first set). Also, have such objects been studied, and do they have names?

For example, consider $n = 5$ and $k = 2$. Then, consider the following permutation of $2$-size subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ (where I omit set brackets and commas for simplicity):
$$12, 23, 34, 45, 51, 13, 35, 52, 24, 41.$$

However, I don't think there exists such a permutation for $n = 4$ and $k = 2$.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by a "permutation" of $S_k$ but I want to be sure.  You're looking for a listing of the elements of $S_k$ with the given property.  For $n=4, k=2$, try $12, 23, 31, 34, 24, 14$.  It's pretty easy to see such listings always exist for $k=2$.  If $n$ is odd, "walk around the perimeter" of an $n$-gon by $1$s and then by $2$s, as you've done for $n=5$.  If $n$ is even, do that for an $n-1$-gon and then list (in a manner that preserves the desired property at the ends) all of the pairs that didn't use the omitted vertex.  Should be easier for $k \gt 2$.

Comment: @RobertShore I don't understand your comment about general $n$ and about walking around the perimeter. Could you elaborate? Also, why is it only easier for $k > 2$?

Comment: Label the sides of an $n$-gon in consecutive order.  Your pairs are the labels of edges.  So for odd $n$, just walk around the perimeter and then, when you return to the starting position, walk around the star you get by visiting every other vertex.  I surmise that the problem is easier for $k \gt 2$ simply because overlaps are easier to arrange.

Comment: This question was cross-posted to MO, where it was answered in the comments: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448586 (there is always such a cycle, for any $k \geq 2$)